# Alert prompt is showing every time i edit my text input field in react native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, alert

I need quick help, please. When I put an invalid email and hit enter it shows me in the alert prompt that email is invalid but  Whenever I am typing in my text box to correct my email the alert prompt is showing every time. I need to get rid of these. please, somebody, help me.

```
<View style={styles.inputContainer}>
            <TextInput
              autoCapitalize="none"
              autoCompleteType="off"
              autoCorrect={false}
              value={username}
              onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({username: text})}
              placeholder="Email"
              underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
              style={styles.textInput}></TextInput>
          </View>
```

The error alert prompt code

```
 <View>{this.state.error ? Alert.alert('Email invalid') : null}</View>
```

Comment: If you have the Alert in the render method it's being called in every render unless this.state.error is false. Attempt to only call the alert when the error is being set or clear the error in state.

Comment: Ahh man..Can u pls pls give me little code example..plss

Comment: onChangeText is call every time you are typing, thus your Alert in the view is called each time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While you got the error `this.state.error` remain `true` and when you enter text into `textInput` on each render this error executes again, Solution for this is either remove this error state from render or set state false after showing error.

```
 <View>{this.state.error ? Alert.alert('Email invalid') : null}</View>
```

Remove above line from render or make sure this line not execute after displaying error on the fisrst attempt by putting your `error state` to `false`